# Helping on how to improve in the online world

Tags: self-learning, online-resources

I had a bad Math teacher (really, terrible), and I also didn't imagine that was such a lovely world and in every thing we do, Math can be applied.

Plus I took the technical path in school (Industrial Electronics), so the area of learning was a bit different than the normal school as the technical path would put us into a new job at the end of the 12 grade (high-school), so we lack or not went depth enough important areas like derivation and integration ...

when I went to the university... well... that was **alien cryptography to me**, and soon realized that I would be better with 1 year off school learning what I never gave.

My point now (and passed almost 16 years of university days), with so much online courses for all developing languages such as PHP, .NET, Ruby... (I'm a developer, so it's eay for my to find the best online courses as I'm in the area) is there a good one that we know, well... Mathematics!

since Matrix numbers to linear functions... **that teach us to re-like Math above all**...

I'm with a certain dificult finding such courses/tutorials :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well such courses are available in numerous sites. Both quantity and quality are admirable.

To begin with:

MIT's opencourseware- a complete archive of pdfs and video lectures with many subjects in Math, physics, engineering and whatnot.

http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/#mathematics

Berkeley's version of the opencourseware:

http://webcast.berkeley.edu/series.html#c,d,Mathematics

Stanford has started interactive online courses. You have to register-but all free- and they will keep posting lectures notes, videos and even quizzes. You have to complete those and your assignments etc. are also graded accordingly.

http://see.stanford.edu/see/courses.aspx

ISI Bangalore also has some course notes etc. on their site.

http://www.isibang.ac.in/~statmath/resource/notes.html

Plus, for a layman's intuitive introduction to any mathematical topic, there are wikipedia and wolphram mathworld.

All this is of course tip of the iceberg. Countless other sites have much to share as well. But I hope these sites will be useful as a good starter for you.

Comment: This courses are really the "american" way of teaching, witch for an European, it's a terrible way to learn :( and that's very well described in the [The Finland Phenomenon](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bcC2l8zioIw) and they're very wide range and not one-on-one videos... I was looking for something else

Comment: Well I would suggest availing yourself of whatever the net has to offer..I personally find such courses very much helpful. For example, the linear algebra course by prof. Gilbert Strang of MIT is awesome, as is the machine learning course by Stanford. One-on-one is the best method, no doubt, but in absence of such lectures, one must do best with what one has. As for Finland phenomenon, I would only say that different countries-->different scenarios-->different methods.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one resource you might want to cosider:
“The Math Reference project is essentially a self-paced tutorial/archive, written in English/html, that takes the reader through modern mathematics using modern techniques.” link to main page:
http://www.mathreference.com/main.html